# In kendo scatter chart set the values of series as object

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have an issue with scatter chart whenever I am giving the series value like below it's not accepting and graph is not getting generate and if I use  type: "scatter", it will work

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: **$("#divGraph").kendoChart({
                        seriesDefaults: {
                            tooltip: {
                                visible: true,
                            },
                            type: "scatter",
                            field: "value",
                            categoryField: "date",                         
                        },
                        series: series,**

Comment: Please see the above code